# Issues with border-box and content-box when styling a datepicker header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style what is to become a datepicker. The issue is that my header does not seem to fully align with its container, so that there is some space between the header and the container border:

[image: my image]

I know this is probably some nitty gritty detail I am missing out on, but maybe somebody can help me find it:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar__header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calendar {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;

    width: 45rem; 
    height: 46.4rem; 
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-sizing: content-box; 

    position: relative;
}

.calendar__header {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem; 
    padding: 0 2rem; 
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What is very strange for me is that the behaviour seems to differ on whether I am displaying the result on my 27'' monitor or on my notebook. I cannot see this gap on my monitor, but it is quite obvious on my notebook.

Comment: it seems this is related to the border of the calendar-container. If I change this border to have a width of 4px instead of 2px, everything looks fine. Only, I don't want a border of 4px. Removing the border entirely works fine as well, but I really do want to have a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead use `box-shadow` like this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calendar {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;

    width: 45rem; 
    height: 46.4rem; 
/*     border: 2px solid black; */
    box-shadow:inset  0 0 0  5px #000;
    box-sizing: content-box; 

    position: relative;
}

.calendar__header {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem; 
    padding: 0 2rem; 
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar__header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: using box-shadow works like a charm! Thx so much, Dhaifallah! I am a bit bummed though, that it doesn't work with border.

Comment: No need dude I've acutally spent sometime searching but no luck, and yeah I've never focused on such detail :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275530#c_ts1638360152) that was introduced in Chromium when they revamped the algorithm that deals with fractional pixels. Don't expect this to be fixed any time soon. Currently the only way to fix it is working with fixed pixel widths, to guarantee that no fractional pixel values are being computed.

The reason you're seeing this on your hi dpi notebook screen is exactly that - a CSS pixel is being represented by more than one physical pixel, resulting in a different rendered result than on your 27" monitor, which I assume you are running at the full physical resolution.

Comment: oh. Well, thx so much for the explanation, conexxo! That makes a lot of sense. Just one question though: I have changed my CSS file such that I am no longer specifying sizes in rem, but in px and I have made sure that all sizes are given in integers. I still encounter the same issue though and I am, therefore, wondering what you mean by `Currently the only way to fix it is working with fixed pixel widths`. Does this simply mean I have to specify sizes in px?

Comment: That should fix it on any screen with a device-to-pixel-ratio of 1. What happens on a hi dpi display cannot reliably be predicted. You will also probably notice that your problem won't occur on every possible zoom level.

Comment: ah ok. That's disappointing. Anyways, thx so much for the explanation! I have upvoted your answer, because it's a perfect explanation, I have just tried out @Daifallahs answer though and it seems to solve my issue, so I accepted his answer.